# winsock2: recvfrom() function ends with error 10022 (Invalid argument)

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, visual-studio-2017, winsock2

I am working on a UDP socket in C++ that is a client and also a server at one time. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and run it on Windows 7. I have some troubles with recvfrom() function, that is ending with "invalid argument" error. I think socket is okay, sockaddr_in structs are okay, thread is okay and even the while-loop with sendto() function is okay. But the thread ends after calling a recvfrom() function and I really don't know where the problem is...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void printMessage(SOCKET s, SOCKADDR_IN destAddr) {

    char message[100];
    int result, error;
    int addrSize = sizeof(destAddr);
    do {
        printf("som v threade\n");
        result = recvfrom(s, message, 100, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&destAddr, &addrSize);
        printf("%d\n", result);

        if (result < 0) {
            error = WSAGetLastError();
            printf("%d\n", error);
        }

        if (result > 0)
            printf("%s", message);

    } while (result > 0);

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    WORD dllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(dllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) {
        printf("Winsock startup failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int dstPort = 49999;
    int srcPort = 49999;

    SOCKADDR_IN destaddr, srcaddr;
    SOCKET s;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (s < 0) {
        printf("Error creating socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    destaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    destaddr.sin_port = htons(dstPort);

    srcaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srcaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    srcaddr.sin_port = htons(srcPort);


    bind(s, (SOCKADDR*)&srcaddr, sizeof(srcaddr));

    thread receiving (printMessage, s, destaddr);
    receiving.detach();

    while (1) {
        char message[100];

        printf("Write a message:");
        scanf("%s", message);

        if (sendto(s, message, sizeof(message), 0, (SOCKADDR *) &destaddr, sizeof(destaddr)) < 0) {
            printf("Message not sent");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't error-checking `bind()`. You should call `WSAGetLastError()` *before* calling `printf()`, or any other system calls, and you should reinitialize `addrSize` every time around the loop.

Comment: And looping until the received count is zero is futile unless you know that (a) the peer is going to send a zero-length packet to terminate the sending and (b) it hasn't been reordered ahead of a datagram, which you can't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code 10022 is `WSAEINVAL`. Per the [`recvfrom()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120.aspx) documentation:

> WSAEINVAL
>
> **The socket has not been bound with `bind()`**, or an unknown flag was specified, or `MSG_OOB` was specified for a socket with `SO_OOBINLINE` enabled, or (for byte stream-style sockets only) `len` was zero or negative.

You are not doing any error handling to make sure your `bind()` call is not failing. Or even that you are calling the correct `bind()` function to begin with. WinSock and STL both have their own `bind()` functions, but your [use of `using namespace std` masks that fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/).

Also, you need to reset `addrSize` each time you call `recvfrom()`, as it could modify the value.  It expects you to pass in your max buffer size, and then it outputs the size actually written to the buffer.

Also, you are not calling `WSAGetLastError()` at the right time. You need to call it **immediately** after a failed WinSock call, before doing *anything* else. In other words, don't call `printf()` before calling `WSAGetLastError()`, as it might potentially reset the error code.

Also, if `recvfrom()` reads successfully, you are assuming the data is null terminated, but that is not guaranteed.  You need to pass `result` as a parameter to `printf()`.

And, you really should not be mixing C style I/O with C++. Use C++ style I/O instead.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void printMessage(SOCKET s)
{
    char message[100];
    int result, error, addrSize;
    SOCKADDR_IN clientaddr;

    do {
        std::cout << "som v threade" << std::endl;
        addrSize = sizeof(clientaddr);
        result = recvfrom(s, message, 100, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&clientaddr, &addrSize);
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            error = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cout << "Receive failed. Error: " << error << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "Received " << result << " byte(s) from " << inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port) << std::endl;
        if (result > 0) {
            std::cout.write(message, result);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while (result > 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    WORD dllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    WSADATA wsaData;    
    int result, error;

    result  = WSAStartup(dllVersion, &wsaData);
    if (result != 0) {
        std::cout << "Winsock startup failed. Error: " << result << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Socket creation failed. Error: " << error << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    unsigned short dstPort = 49999;
    unsigned short srcPort = 49999;

    SOCKADDR_IN destaddr = {};
    SOCKADDR_IN srcaddr = {};

    destaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    destaddr.sin_port = htons(dstPort);

    srcaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srcaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    srcaddr.sin_port = htons(srcPort);

    result = ::bind(s, (SOCKADDR*)&srcaddr, sizeof(srcaddr));
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Socket bind failed. Error: " << error << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::thread receiving(printMessage, s);
    receiving.detach();

    std::string message;
    do {
        std::cout << "Write a message: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, message);
        result = sendto(s, message.c_str(), message.size(), 0, (SOCKADDR *) &destaddr, sizeof(destaddr));
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            error = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cout << "Message not sent. Error: " << error << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

had same problem with me after including files like

```
#include <thread> /*or*/ #include <future>
```

turns out it was a confusion between `bind()` and `std::bind()`.

remove `using namespace std;` or simply use `::bind()`.